# Where to put binaries so they are always in path and can be found easily

Tags: linux, path, file-location

I am making quite some binaries, scripts, etc. that I want to install easily (using my own [RPM packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager)). Since I want them accessible for everyone, my intuition would be to put them in /usr/bin;

- no need to change PATH

However, my executables now disappear in a pool of all the others; how can I find back all the executables I put there in an easy way?

I was thinking of:

- A subdirectory in /usr/bin (I know I cannot do this; just to illustrate my thinking).
- Another directory (/opt/myself/bin) and linking each executable to /usr/bin (lots of work).
- Another directory (/opt/myself/bin) and linking the directory to /usr/bin (is this possible?).

What would be the "best, most Linux-compliant way" to do this?

Comment: I just realized I'd better post this question on unix & linux stack overflow... I reposted the question there.

Answer (score 4):

Most systems have `/usr/local/bin` in their PATH. It is meant for exactly this purpose, to contain binaries installed locally rather than from the repositories. Also there is `/usr/local/sbin` for locally-installed superuser binaries.

See the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY).

Comment: /usr/local/bin/ is only for local binaries, not really for binaries that are distributed in an rpm..

Comment: Yes, but he apparently wants to treat them as local, otherwise just use the normal directories.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward solution would be to change the system-wide PATH variable. All the files in `/etc/profile.d` are automatically sourced on login, so adding a file which changes the PATH variable for all users.

For example, do the following as root:

`cat <<EOF >/etc/profile.d/custom_path.sh
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/myself/bin
EOF`